# Use of undeclared identifier - xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6

The code compiles fine on all simulators. If I switch to device I get a bunch of "use of undeclared identifier" errors. All of a sudden.

Comment: show the crash report

Comment: It's an Xcode bug. I installed the latest and everything worked fine